# gpg-plugin for squirrelmail won't create keypairs

Tags: php, plugins, gnupg, squirrelmail

Today i installed the squirrelmail gpg plugin.

But a problem arises when i want to generate a new keypair.

When i fill in the keypair creation form and send it away i'll go to a next screen that says:

Your key is being generated... please be patient!

Well after a hour, it just seems to be stuck. In fact i need to restart my
browser(firefox and ie also) if i want to go to my webmail again.

I can't find any errors in the apache/php logs, it just keeps trying to load and won't
get any further.

Has anyone a suggestion, what go's wrong or maybe more important how i can find out what's going wrong? (since there are no visible errors...)

Gr,
Hermes.